# Why does Jooq code-generation break with PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, build.gradle, postgis, jooq

**Context** - I am trying out Postgres' Geographic Information System extension [PostGis](https://postgis.net/) that enables stories latitude and longitudes as [Point](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html) and operations on it.

[If I understand correctly](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/) then I need to add a custom converter that can convert the `point` between JOOQ and PostGis and add it to the gradle file.

**Problem** - When I generate the jooq-code, few files are generated incorrectly and have the fields defined twice which fail compilation. These are:

```
<configured-generation-dir>/tables/StValuecount.java
<configured-generation-dir>/tables/records/StValuecountRecord.java
<configured-generation-dir>/tables/records/StValuepercentRecord.java
<configured-generation-dir>/tables/_StValuecount.java
<configured-generation-dir>/tables/records/_StValuecountRecord.java
<configured-generation-dir>/tables/_StHistogram.java
<configured-generation-dir>/tables/records/_StHistogramRecord.java
<configured-generation-dir>/tables/_StQuantile.java
```

**Gradle config** =>

```
jooq{
    myAwesomeApp(sourceSets.main){
        logging = 'WARN'
        jdbc {
            driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
            url = db_url
            user = db_user
            password = db_password
        }
        generator {
            name = 'org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator'
            strategy {
                name = 'org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGeneratorStrategy'
            }
            database {
                name = 'org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase'
                inputSchema = 'public'
                forcedTypes {
                    forcedType {
                        userType = 'org.postgis.Point'
                        converter = 'com.example.JooqBreaksWithPostGis.jooq.converters.PostgresPointJooqConverter'
                        expression = '.*\\.point'
                        types = '.*'
                    }
                }
            }
            generate {
                routines = false
                relations = true
                deprecated = false
                records = true
                immutablePojos = false
                fluentSetters = true
            }
            target {
                packageName = 'jooq.fancy.app'
                directory = 'src/main/java/generated'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

I have also created a minimal [project](https://github.com/raj-saxena/JooqBreaksWithPostGis) where I have reproduced the problem in case someone wants to quickly try it.

#### Steps to reproduce

- Checkout project

```sh
git clone git@github.com:raj-saxena/JooqBreaksWithPostGis.git
```

- Go to the project directory and start postgis docker container with

```sh
docker-compose up
```

- Similarly, to remove postgis docker container run

```sh
docker-compose down
```

- Run migrations that add a simple `City` table containing `Point` type with

```sh
./gradlew flywayMigrate
```

- I have added few rows in a second migration to verify if the DB structure was working. Details to connect to Postgres instance in the build.gradle file.
- Generate jooq files with

```sh
./gradlew generateMyAwesomeAppJooqSchemaSource
```

- Verify that the files are generated in the configured `src/main/java/generated` directory.
- Verify that the files mentioned above fail to compile.

---

Taking Lukas' [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55941212/3074229), I added the exclude configuration to the jooq config as below:

```
            database {
                name = 'org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase'
                ...
                excludes = '.*ST_ValueCount' +
                        '|.*St_Valuepercent' +
                        '|.*St_Histogram' +
                        '|.*St_Quantile' +
                        '|.*St_Approxhistogram' +
                        '|.*St_PixelOfValue' +
                        '|.*St_Approxquantile' +
                        '|.*ST_Tile'
            }
```

This allowed the code to compile.

Comment: Are those (e.g. `st_valuecount`) overloaded table valued functions?

Comment: For the record, this was also reported as a bug on https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8587

Comment: Would you please explain where the `database` section goes?  I assume you put it in your `build.gradle` file.  Can you please explain where in the file you put it?  Gradle's extensive use of implicit config means makes it incomprehensible to those who have not spent countless hours learning its intricate details.

Comment: @M.Leonhard it's here https://github.com/raj-saxena/JooqBreaksWithPostGis/blob/master/build.gradle#L59-L107

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds a lot like https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4055. jOOQ 3.11 currently cannot handle overloaded table valued functions in any RDBMS that supports table valued functions. Your best option here is to exclude all the affected functions from the code generation, using `<excludes>`:

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-includes-excludes/